# Applicability of the definition of limit for a constant function

Tags: limits, functions

I am giving the following definition of limit (Chiang, *Fundamental methods of mathematical economics*):

> As $v$ approaches a number $N$, the limit of $q=g(v)$ is the number
>   $L$, if, for every neighborhood of $L$ that can be chosen, however
>   small, there can be found a corresponding neighborhood of $N$
>   (excluding the point $v=N$) in the domain of the function such that,
>   for every value of $v$ in that $N$-neighborhood, its image lies in the
>   chosen $L$-neighborhood.

However I don't know how this definition can be applied to the case of a constant function, let's say $q=4$. In that case, I intituivelly know that e.g. $\lim_{x \to 1} q(x) = 4$, but I can't find any neighborhood of 4 for which to find a corresponding neighborhood of 1. As the ONLY value in the range of the function is 4, I can't find any neighborhood of it.

Answer (score 1):

For your constant function, for any neighborhood of $L$ it the case that that every (and so at at least one) neighborhood of $N$ has the property that:

> for every value of $v$ in that $N$-neighborhood, its image lies in the
>   chosen $L$-neighbourhood.

That is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

the interval $(4-\varepsilon,4+\varepsilon)$ is always a Neighborhood of 4, it does not matter if $q(x)$ has any values there or not.

Comment: ok, but then I can't find any *corresponding* value in the domain of $(4-\varepsilon,4+\varepsilon)$, aside for when q=4..

Comment: if by "corresponding value" you mean a $q(x)$ (for some $x$) then there is no need to find such value. $4$ is in every neighborhood of $4$, thats all you need to know.